# Is It Dangerous to Connect Qt5 Signals to a C++14 Lambda With an `auto` Parameter?

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, qt5, c++14

I'm tasked with creating an interface to an external application that's beyond our control. Right now, it's a Qt5 application and we hook into its signals that send out `QExplicitlySharedDataPointer<T>`. In the next couple months, that external application will be removing their dependency on Qt and they've said they will likely switch to sending out `std::shared_ptr<T>` or something similar via some other event method (I don't have more info than that for how we'll be receiving these pointers at the moment).

My goal is to reduce the number of changes we'll need to make in our codebase when they make that change. They confirmed that they aren't going to change T's interface, so my first thought was "I wonder if Qt5 allows you to use templates with slots." The answer to that is no, but I wasn't discouraged. I managed to come up with a workaround, but I'm not sure it's completely safe. I'm hoping somebody here more knowledgeable than myself can explain what's happening under the hood in this code and determine whether it's safe or not.

My idea was to use C++14 lambdas with auto parameters to set up a handler that can accept any pointer type. That function can pull out a reference to the object (shared pointer still in scope, so no concern about the object being deleted and my reference becoming invalid) and pass it to a function that extracts data from it. This should separate how we receive the data from how we extract it.

Here's the class I've been using to test this:

```
// testclass.h
class TestClass : public QObject
{
    // This is just a stand-in for the data type we'll be
    // receiving. The public interface for this class shouldn't
    // be changing.
    class TestData : public QSharedData
    {
        public:
        // The data in the class isn't important for now because
        // I'm assuming the interface to the pointed-to instance
        // will be the same
        TestData() : value(5) { }

        private:
        int value;
    };

    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit TestClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    signals:
        void sendRawPointer(TestData* ptr);
        void sendStdShared(std::shared_ptr<TestData> ptr);
        void sendQtShared(QExplicitlySharedDataPointer<TestData> ptr);
};




// testclass.cpp
TestClass::TestClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    // I know the pointed-to type will always be the same, so I 
    // can get a const& to it and use its interface without worrying
    // about the specific type of pointer being used
    auto extractData = [=](const TestData& data) {
        std::cout << "Received data: " << data.value << "\n";
    };

    // This is the key piece. It should allow me to receive any pointer
    // type that supports the dereference operator. That's all of the
    // pointer types I'm aware of, assuming they don't try to roll their
    // own specific for this class
    auto receivePointer = [=](auto ptr) {
        try {
            const auto& data = *ptr;
            extractData(data);
        } catch(...) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to receive data. The signal must use "
              << "a pointer type that supports operator*()\n";
        }
    };

    // EDIT: Forgot these lines originally.
    connect(this, &TestClass::sendRawPointer,
            receivePointer);
    connect(this, &TestClass::sendStdShared,
            receivePointer);
    connect(this, &TestClass::sendQtShared,
            receivePointer);

    auto rawPointer = new TestData();
    auto stdShared = std::shared_ptr<TestData>(new TestData());
    auto qtShared = QExplicitlySharedDataPointer<TestData>(new TestData());

    emit sendRawPointer(rawPointer);
    emit sendStdShared(stdShared);
    emit sendQtShared(qtShared);
};
```

My questions are

1. Is this safe to do? I'm leaving this project in a few months and the removal of the Qt dependency will be after I leave. I'm trying to leave something in place that won't break. There will likely be changes required because it won't be Qt signals, but it would be nice to not have to completely change how we receive data, down to the pointer type.
2. If this is appropriate, is this the correct way to do this? This seems like an awesome use of auto to me (although it does require the exception handling in the case of receiving a type that doesn't have `operator*()`). Is there some better way to do this that I should be looking at instead?

Comment: Fixed those braces for you.

Comment: `auto` lamdbas are nothing special. They are essentially templated functions/classes. You will end up with multiple "versions" for every type you use. This probably isn't an issue unless you attempt to rely on static locals inside the lambda.